# Show that a quadratic function is always positive for all real values of $x$

Tags: quadratics

How can I show that $x^2 +x +1$ is aways positive for all values of $x$? Do I use discriminant or completing the square?

Comment: Either will do. I prefer completing the square. And because of an allergy to fractions, I prefer to say that $x^2+x+1$ is always positive if and only if $4x^2+4x+4$ is always positive, and $4x^2+4x+4=(2x+1)^2+3$.

Comment: Complete the square to get $x^2+x+1=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2+x+1$

$=(x^2+2x+1)-x$

$=(x+1)^2-x$

Now,$(x+1)$ $>$ $x$.

So,$(x+1)^2$ $>$ $x$

So,$(x+1)^2$ $-$ $x$ is positive.